# How to define an indicator variable for pixels within certain distance of borders?

Tags: arcmap

I have a polygon shapefile including 7000 polygons of different shapes that cover the whole world. I also have small pixels that cover the whole world.

Now, for every border between every pair of polygons, I need to define a variable indicating the pixels that are within 100km of the border. How would you do this using ArcMap?

Comment: Are the pixels rasters? If so you could create a 100 kilometre buffer in the interior of each polygon, rasterize the buffer, and use the raster calculator to find the pixels in the buffer

Comment: Nice suggestion. I am going to try it. What tool is the best to create buffer around borders of a polygon shapefile?

Comment: There's a tool called 'buffer' in the analysis tool pack. [link to tool description](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/buffer.htm)

Comment: @jdavid05 Thanks! This was very helpful. You should put this in the answer section. It works. Just one thing isn't clear to me: the polygon created with buffer tool includes the original polygon as well, right? It seems that buffer only augments the polygon on all its borders by 100km. This is still helpful, but I thought the buffer would be a strip of 200km around the border of the polygon.

Comment: You have to play around with the settings a bit to get the output you want. You can use dissolve fields if you only want to put a buffer around a group of polygons and you can change the side type to outside only if that fits the project better (I think this requires a higher licence level). Probably what you want is outside only which may not be possible with a basic arcMap licence. In that case, you could try QGIS or try to find a different work around.

Comment: Thanks. Very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

One simple way to do this is using "Spatial Join" tool.

First, use Spatial Join (one to N) from points to polygons, with option "Intersect". Then again use Spatial Join (one to N) from points to polygons, but using the option "Within a Distance" and specifying 100km.

The subtract of the two outcomes above will indicate points within 100km of borders.